# Application for teaching programming to classmates

Tags: windows, mac, skype

I'm looking for an application i can use to teach my classmates how to program.

Well, i give some classmates courses of programming, and i would like a software that lets me share my screen, audio talk, chat, and send multimedia. I have tried Skype to accomplish this, but it gets really buggy or disconnects some of my classmates, and really don't like it for teaching. Im using Mac and my classmates use Windows. Is there any software that i can use that meets my requirements?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Thank you very much, i asked the same question in stackoverflow they sent me here, to superuser.. i will keep this in mind

Comment: The users over there don't always get things right ;)

Answer (score 1):

My best bet would be using **Net Support Manager**.

Here are just a few of the features it offers:
 **Multi platform** (many types OS )

> 1. Watch, Share or Control the screen, keyboard and mouse of a
>      workstation irrespective of colour resolution, network protocol or
>      operating system.
> 2. Optimise the Remote Control colour quality when managing systems
>      over very slow connections.
> 3. Monitor the screens of all connected systems with real-time
>      thumbnails. Mouse over a selected PC to zoom your view.
> 4. Scan multiple systems, cycle through one or multiple workstations
>      displaying their screens on your Control console.
> 5. Show your screen, a selected monitor or just a selected application
>      to any number of connected computers for real-time instruction.
> 6. Annotate your screen with a range of drawing tools during a Remote
>      Control session or Show session.
> 7. **Full Text and Audio Chat and Messaging between two or multiple
>      systems.**
> 8. Full Audio Chat during a Remote Control session.
> 9. Capture screenshots during a session for future reference.
> 10. Record screen activity to a video "replay file" for training or
>        security.
> 11. To aid both training and the effectiveness of support, a Whiteboard
>        feature is also provided from within a chat session.

I suggest you try the trial license and see the features first.Last time i used it trial was limited to 10 computers.

See more features here:http://www.netsupportmanager.com/windows.asp

Downloads here:http://www.netsupportmanager.com/downloads.asp

(Download net support manager = best)

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing) and make sure you "block quote" quoted material ([Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help)). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.